# Would a question about business rules that shape a program be on-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

I would like to know if Stack Overflow, which regularly handles questions about programming, can also be used to ask about business logic behind such program implementations.

I lack an expert and need someone's expert advice in a field (that knows such business rules) to help me identify the logic that I will then code.

But I am not sure if business rules behind a program implementation are on-topic on Stack Overflow. I have the feeling it will be off-topic.

Comment: Could you give an example? I guess most (if not all) questions about business logic will be off-topic.

Comment: I need to understand the workflow (logically) of a specific procedure  so i can code it. I have doubt and question about the workflow as i understood and maybe an expert in the field can help me. If stackoverflow is not suitable which stack should?

Comment: The business logic/workflow as in "I have the data stored in the following dataframe, how can I calculate X" or in "When the secretary wants to order for more than X euros, they need a signature from their boss"?

Comment: About the voting: Voting on meta works different than on the main site. It either means that the question is asked poorly, or that people disagree with what you ask. Also note, that votes on meta do not change your reputation.

Comment: @BDL somewhat, just to be precise and give more context, I would like to know best practice to handle payment atomicity, in checkout process. Clearly depending on the context any business handle checkout differently. So i understand is subjective

Comment: Why are you not asking the people who you are doing this for? (Rhetorical.) That is who you should be asking. PS Please clarify via edits, not comments.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Business rules are subjectively defined, so there's no "right" answer.  Given any specific business requirement, someone could come up with a myriad of ways to implement it.  This is why it'd be off-topic.

Comment: I understand your point, i think i can try to limitate the scope of "business rule" to make less subjective, but yes it's difficult and near impossible. Did you know if there is some stack that is suitable istead of SO?

Comment: @Skary:  You may just need to hire a contractor to help you with this.  Stack Exchange couldn't help you with this.

Comment: I also find that it can be very much influenced by the actual business itself. As an example, software in the healthcare market tends to be heavily restricted by hefty rules and guidelines (and archaic service models...) which frequently force you to implement things in... unorthodox ways. Only people with domain knowledge will understand the how and why and especially the why not, throwing it into a pool as large as Stack Overflow can only end in tears. Stack is good for programming problems, not business problems.